# cygwin ssh no putty yes?

Tags: ssh, cygwin, putty, passphrase

I generated a keys with putty w/ no passphrase. putty works fine, but now i installed cygwin and would like to use ssh to login. For some reason i'm prompted for a passphrase?  why?  putty just logs straight in? i don't want to have to generate a new key and annoy the network admins.  here is what it looks like in cygwin:
$ ssh -i Documents\ and\ Settings/xxxxx/My\ Documents/xxxxx\ putty\ keys/private\ key.ppk dev.xxxxxx.com
Enter passphrase for key 'Documents and Settings/xxxxx/My Documents/xxxxx putty keys/private key.ppk':
Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 19):

Putty uses its own .ppk format for keyfiles, and Cygwin's ssh probably can't read them correctly.

Solution: convert the .ppk file to OpenSSH key format with puttygen.exe.

Comment: I have a key pair I generated with openssh and then converted into putty keys. oddly enough the putty one works but the openssh doesn't. tried using puttygen but no luck with that either. any ideas?

Comment: @user1084563: So you have a key pair generated with openssh and it doesn't work with openssh? Sorry, I don't think puttygen can fix that. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: It's really useful. My cygwin ssh utils now working! Menu Conversions/Export OpenSSH key. Thank you Joonas!

Answer (score 6):

You need to get "puttygen.exe" from the putty webpage http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html to convert your key to the OpenSSH format. Then it should just work.

Answer (score 2):

If you can login with putty, there is no need to "annoy the network admins". Just generate a new key with cygwin, then login with putty and place your new public key in your .ssh/authorized_keys file. You should now be able to login with cygwin's ssh.

EDIT:

By the way, a sure way to "piss off" any admin is to use unencrypted keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can export PuTTY keys to OpenSSH format and append them to your .ppk file, so that it becomes a valid key for ssh-add.

Just export the private key with PuTTYGen then add it to the .ppk file, then you should be able to ssh-add it. But note that when you edit the .ppk itself with PuTTYGen, it will ovewrite the file.

You can also use a script like this for adding a .ppk file into your SSH agent:

```
file=~/`basename $0`.tmp
trap "rm -v $file" EXIT
echo -n "Password: "
read -s pwd
echo $pwd | puttygen -P -q -O private-openssh $1 -o $file
ssh-add $file
```

Source: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~renatosilva/+junk/scripts/view/head:/ppk-add.sh